# Undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass when trying to write to db in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

From an active record method in rails (streamlined to illustrate the flow only):

```
class Model
  include Mongoid:Document
  include Mongoid:Timestamps

  belongs_to :record
  belongs_to :structure
  has_one :sim_engine, dependent: :destroy

  def init                        #Line 22
    if new_record?
      self.structure = record.structure
      self.sim_engine = SimEngine.create(function1,other_inputs...)
    end
  end

  def function1
    input_1 = ...
    input_2 = ...
    function1_hash = [ ]
    ...
    m = function2(input_1,input_2)
    function1_hash += m

  rescue Exception => e
    throw "Error in record #{record.id}: #{e.message}"     #Line 683
  end

  def function2(input_1,input_2)
    input_1.each do |value|
    function2_hash << value
  end

  temp = input_2.anotherClassFunctionCall()
  function2_hash << temp
end
```

when I run:

```
Model.create!(record: 314675)
```

I get the following error trace:

```
ArgumentError: uncaught throw "Error in record 314675: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1311: in 'throw'
from /srv/app/models/model.rb:683: in 'function1'    # See above sample code
from /srv/app/models/model.rb:22: in 'init'          # See above sample code
# The line numbers are commented in the above sample code
```

I am trying to figure out why the error exception is being thrown out and here are my assumptions:

1. The record that I'm trying to write to the db (mongodb) has not been defined yet.
2. There is an error in the `function1` method that needs to be addressed.
3. There is an error in the `function2` method that is inherited by `function1`.

Comment: would you be able to post some of the stack trace?

Comment: can we see the real code? You're not even calling that `init` method anywhere.

Comment: The error message should be giving you a line number where it's failing. Did you look at that? You haven't indicated what part of your code is being implicated.

Comment: There are actually several things wrong. My guess is that, that particular error is coming from your last line in the Model class. `function2_hash` is being treated as an array, but it is not defined in that scope (it was defined only within the function2 scope). When you use the `<<` operator on an undefined array, you get an error.

Comment: @richessler I added trace.

Comment: @MichaelCruz It is defined in the actual code, i've tried to streamline it here. Thanks!

Comment: @sevenseacat Doesn't .create fire off 'init'??

Comment: Well, it rescuing from exception in function1, so something in there is happening, but I think you may have left out the code that is triggering the exception. Also, you don't need to throw an error from rescue, just handle it in the rescue block. If you do throw, you need to have the calling method catch and handle the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason for

> ArgumentError: uncaught throw "Error in record 314675: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass'

was primarily from an incomplete set of input variables that is required by the ***def init*** method. Because this was an **ArgumentError** that was thrown from the **function1** method, I was only invested in debugging **function1**. The original model takes in 7 input variables, including **function1**. I realized that couple of the input variables did not match the data type, e.g., the model takes in integers while the input variable was in string.